# Unable to extract content using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to print price of the selenium object using class attribute extracted from the page. Using the same class I can extract from some products, but not for all. What is the mistake I'm doing here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/Nothing-Phone-Black-128-RAM/dp/B0BKZVF7VV/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2V22OHL4YXGHF&keywords=nothing+phone+1&qid=1678089940&sprefix=nothing%2Caps%2C209&sr=8-2')

price_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-offscreen")
print(price_element.text)

driver.quit()
```

I was expecting the print statement should provide the price of the product.

Comment: What element are you getting at? Because `price_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-offscreen") ` selects multiple elements, that's why you don't get results.

Comment: I want to get the just price of the product which is in class "a-offscreen". How can I get the one I want?

Comment: many products have that class. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector

```
price_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-offscreen")
```

selects multiple elements.

To get precisely price of the main product try using this

```
price_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div")
```

Comment: I wonder why it worked when I used "https://www.amazon.in/Cookware-Induction-Friendly-Sandwich-Pressure/dp/B00EYZT8MS/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=XNWKRH9NS0CF&keywords=cooker+3+litres&qid=1678090114&sprefix=coock%2Caps%2C221&sr=8-1-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&psc=1" , even this has multiple elements, but worked using price_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-offscreen")

Comment: It depends, maybe in this case your element was the first in list of elements with the same class. That's why you need precise selectors, make sure you are selecting only one element.